# FEM of beam with unsymmetrical UDL

Tags: finite-element-method

I have two different UDLs for 6.5m and 3m spaced side by side on a primary beam. If I were to calculate the FEM of this beam, how should I proceed as there're no formulas for situation particularly like this (unsymmetrical UDL on beam) on the FEM Formula sheet. Kindly advice me on this matter ,tq.

Comment: If you do not agree with the responses provided, you shall edit your question with a loading diagram, or ask questions on the suggestions which you don't seem to grab.

Comment: What is the beam made of - wood, steel, concrete...Also, for wood or steel beam, is the beam continuous over the major beam, or there are two beam segments that end before the major beam and build into it through the shear connections? The scenarios are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can break-up the problem into multiple separate problems.

Ex. a cantilever beam with a uniform load, UL, and supported at the free end, can be broken into the deflection of the UL without the suport at the free end
AND
the same beam without the UL but with the resultant load at the free end alone.

Summing the deflections of both cases results in the deflection of the initial problem.

Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classic method to find the "Fixed End Moment" or utilize a table as shown below by superposition - separate the beam with two loading cases, either case 1 + case 7, or case 7 with each UDL on its corresponding location.

[image]